# Return list of items to a controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have these tables in my database, Presses, Paper, and PressPaperSpeeds:

```
Presses
----------------
PressID (PK)
Name

Paper
----------------
PaperID (PK)
Name

PressPaperSpeeds
----------------
PressPaperSpeedID (PK)
PressID (FK)
PaperID (FK)
Speed
```

When I'm adding a Press, I'd like to have a table to add PressPaperSpeeds. In one column, it contains all the Papers, and in another column, a textbox to enter the Speed. Here's what I have on my view page to create a Press:

```
<table>
    <% foreach(Paper paper in Model.Papers) { %>            
        <tr>
            <td><%: paper.Name %></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>       
    <% } %>
</table>
```

My view model contains `Papers`, which is just a collection of all Papers from the database.

Here's my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PressesViewModel viewModel)
{
    Press press = new Press();
    TryUpdateModel(press);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {      
        //somehow get all values for Press Paper Speeds and save them here
        DBRepository.SavePress(press);
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = press.PressID });
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

How can I get the **PaperID** and **Speed** value from the textbox for that table of speeds, and return it to my controller?

Comment: do you want public class Press{ public int PressID{get;set;}public string Name{get;set;} public EntitySet<PressPaperSpeed>{get;set;}} object to be passed to your controller action method

Comment: @Muhammad - Preferably, yes. Or `IEnumerable<PressPaperSpeed>`

Answer (score 0):

ok then i will create my viewmodel like

```
public class PressViewModel
{
public int PressID{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
public IEnumerable<VMPressPaperSpeed> PressPaperSpeeds{get;set;}
}

public class VMPressPaperSpeed{
public int PressPaperSpeedID{get;set;}
public int PressID{get;set;}
public int PaperID{get;set;}
public string PaperName{get;set;}// for view purpose 
public int Speed{get;set;}//change data type for speed accordingly
}
```

My controller would look like

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var model = new PressViewModel();
  model.PressPaperSpeeds = _SomeRepository.PopulatePaperDataLeavingIDsUntouched();
  // after this line i will have all paper information inside my viewmodel's property that will be passed to view and user will enter corresponding speeds for current press   
}
```

My view will look like

```
    <%:Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Name)>
    <%:Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Name)>
    <%:Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ID)%>

    <%for(int i=0;i<Model.PressPaperSpeeds.Count;i++){%>
    <%:Html.PaperName%>
    <%:Html.Hidden("Model.PressPaperSpeeds["+i+"].PressPaperID" Model.PressPaperSpeeds[i].PressPaperSpeedID)%>
<%:Html.Hidden("Model.PressPaperSpeeds["+i+"].PressID" Model.PressPaperSpeeds[i].PressID)%>
<%:Html.Hidden("Model.PressPaperSpeeds["+i+"].PaperID" Model.PressPaperSpeeds[i].PaperID)%>
<%:Html.TextBox("Model.PressPaperSpeeds["+i+"].Speed" Model.PressPaperSpeeds[i].Speed)%>
<%:Html.Hidden("Model.PressPaperSpeeds["+i+"].PaperName" Model.PressPaperSpeeds[i].PaperName)%>
```

put everything in form fill it out and press submit button. go to post action method put a break point and see things will be populated in your viewModel and tryUpdate Model should also work as well but you have to name properties in your viewmodel exactly the way they are in model. Don't miss EntitySet property name.